# What is meant by rate of change with respect to volume?

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative, volume, electromagnetism

In physics we often come across $$\rho=\dfrac{dq}{dV}$$

Does it mean:

$(i)$ $\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta q}{\Delta V}$

OR

$(ii)$ $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x} \right) \right)$

What does the first one mean?

The second one is a mixed partial derivative. Can it be found if $q, \dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x} \right)$ are differentiable?

Comment: The first expression is the limit of the difference quotient of $q$ and $V$, which is the definition of the derivative. This is what I'd assume was meant by "rate of change (of $q$) wrt. volume".

Comment: Is it necessary to tell the shape of volume $V$ which is being shrinked around a point. Otherwise different shapes of $V$ will have different $\frac{dq}{dV}$

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You'd certainly need to know how $q$ and $V$ relate in order to find $\frac{dq}{dV}$.

Comment: Analogous to the usual definition of derivative of a function in one variable: $$\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{\Delta q}{\Delta V}=\lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{q(V+\Delta V)-q(V)}{\Delta V}$$ I don't get what is meant by $q(V+\Delta V)$ and $q(V)$ Also what is the shape of volume $\Delta V$? Should it be a cuboid?

Comment: The term $q$ is a function of volume. For example, if $q$ were the height of a cuboid with fixed base is a function of the volume, then $q(V)$ could refer to a height that corresponds to a volume is $10\ cm^2$. Then, $q(V+\Delta V)$ could refer to the height that corresponded with a tiny increase from the previous volume, e.g. $10.02\ cm^2$. The shape doesn't have to be a cuboid - it could be anything as long as the term $q$ is a function of $V$. Unless $q$ has a specific meaning in this context, in which case you should let us know.